# TikZ: How to decorate one or more rectangle sides?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-decorations, tikz-decorations

[image]

How can I change the left and the right line of a rectangle to 'zigzag'?

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={zigzag,segment length=0.4em, amplitude=.3mm}]
\draw[] (0,3) edge[decorate] (0,0) --+ (0.5,0) edge[decorate, red] (0.5,0) edge[-]+ (0,0);

\draw[xshift=2cm] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,3); 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With two nodes and less explicit coordinations:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}% if you load tikz afterward, no need to put it as documentclass option
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, positioning}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={inner sep=0pt, minimum width=.5cm, minimum height=3cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={zigzag,segment length=0.4em, amplitude=.3mm}]
\node[mynode] (A) {};
\draw (A.north west) -- (A.north east) edge[decorate] (A.south east) (A.south east) -- (A.south west) edge[decorate] (A.north west);
\node[mynode, right=1.5cm of A, draw]  {}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As Ross suggested, with `line cap=round` option in the `\draw`:

```
\draw[line cap=round] (A.north west) -- (A.north east) edge[decorate] (A.south east) (A.south east) -- (A.south west) edge[decorate] (A.north west);
```

the joins are better:

[image]

Another expert told me there is the possibility to decorate part of the path without using `edge`s:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, positioning}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={inner sep=0pt, minimum width=.5cm, minimum height=3cm}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={zigzag,segment length=0.4em, amplitude=.3mm}]
    \node[mynode] (A) {};
    \draw[line cap=round] (A.north west) -- (A.north east) decorate{-- (A.south east)} -- (A.south west) decorate{-- cycle};
    \node[mynode, right=1.5cm of A, draw]  {}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Maybe add `line cap=round` to get better joins.

Answer (score 2):

Try to repeat some coordinates:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={zigzag,segment length=0.4em, amplitude=.3mm}]

\draw[]  (0,0)   edge [decorate] (0,3) (0,3) -- (0.5,3) (0.5,3) edge [decorate] (0.5,0) (0.5,0) -- (0,0);

\draw[xshift=2cm] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah ok, very nice.